# How can I make categories in a image gallery in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hi I'm a graphic designer and very new in programing, I've been learning Python for a while and wanna try something with Django, I'm making my website with Django just for fun and practice and I made this image gallery following some tutorials, but I want to add categorization to the images so in my website I can call some images by categorization and not showing up all the images at once. How can I do that?

MODELS.PY

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    width = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    height = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    image = models.ImageField(null= False, blank = False, width_field="width", height_field="height")
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, auto_now = False)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title

class Meta:
    ordering = ["-timestamp"]
```

VIEWS.PY

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from apps.photos.models import Photo

# Create your views here.
def photo_list(request):
    queryset = Photo.objects.all()
    context = {
    "photos": queryset,
}
return render(request, 'photos/photos.html', context)
```

PHOTOS.HTML

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}

{% block contenido %}
<br>
<br>
{% for photo in photos %}
<h1>{{ photo.title }}</h1>
{% if photo.image %}
<img src="{{ photo.image.url }}" class="img-responsive">
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock  %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your models you can add another field called something like

```
CHOICES = (
            #('what_database_save', 'WHAT USER SEE'),
            ('cat1', 'category'),
            ('cat2', 'category2'),
        )
category = models.Charfield(max_length, choices=CHOICES)
```

if you want you can add choices and later use it in your forms. In your views you can filter the photos by category using the `queryset = Photo.objects.filter(category="cat1")` method

Comment: Perfect it worked, but now how can I access to a certain images by just clicking in a link in my web?, for example if wanted to view the images in 'cat1' category. How can I do this?

Comment: let me understand, you want to access to a category clicking a button, image or something like that?

Comment: Exactly here is what i'm trying to do, www.rezzpo.com/portfolio if I click 'Sitios Web', I wanted that only shows the images of that category.

Comment: well you can choose between use ajax, reactjs or redirect to another web page with a 'sitios web' render images

Comment: if you choose redirect, use the same example that I gave you